# Overflow encountered in numpy true division

Tags: python, numpy

I'am trying to implement gradient descent with momentum from scratch in python. While implementing the bias correction for exponentially weighted average I encountered a runtime warning saying 'Overflow encountered in numpy true division'. I'am trying to divide a numpy array with a float which is very small (provided in the code section).

```
for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
            self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)] = (self.beta1*self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)] + (1-self.beta1)*self.dw['dw'+str(i)])
            self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)] = (self.beta1*self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)] + (1-self.beta1)*self.db['db'+str(i)])
            self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)] = self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)].astype('float')
            self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)] = self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)].astype('float')
            self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)] = np.divide(self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)], (1-np.power(self.beta1, t))) # encounterd error in this line
            self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)] = np.divide(self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)], (1-np.power(self.beta1, t))) # and this line aswell
```

dvw and dvb are both dictionaries with numpy array's as values. beta1 value is 0.9 and t is a real number

Comment: Overflow : result too large to be expressed.. try converting arrays to np.float128 dtype  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve the numerical stability of your code by adding:

```
eps=1e-6
for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
    self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)] = (self.beta1*self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)] + (1-self.beta1)*self.dw['dw'+str(i)])
    self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)] = (self.beta1*self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)] + (1-self.beta1)*self.db['db'+str(i)])
    self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)] = self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)].astype('float')
    self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)] = self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)].astype('float')
    self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)] = np.divide(self.dvw['dvw'+str(i)], (eps + 1-np.power(self.beta1, t)))
    self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)] = np.divide(self.dvb['dvb'+str(i)], (eps + 1-np.power(self.beta1, t)))
```

Comment: I used epsilon (1e-6, 1e-7), but it did not work. Still the same warning. Thanks.